# Can't access iframe using jQuery in another domain In IE8-11

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-11

I can't access **iframe** using **jQuery** in localhost or if i use **another domain** In **IE8-11**. 
i use [Smart Demo-bar](http://pixeldima.com/preview/?theme=dima) script it work perfectly on other browsers but in **IE8-11** it must be in some domain or all function provide py Demo-bar break. 

- i have try add an `onload` event to the iframe. (But this will only work if the source in the iframe is from the same domain.)
- Another solution i fond in stackoverflow convert jQuery to JS .

Please if there's way to fix this issues on `IE` i'll be Thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer has a very restrictive set of rules regarding Cross-domain access (as you have just noticed). The sandboxing between the "host" page and the iframe is meant to prevent XSS attacks.

If you are trying to make an ajax call, jQuery provides the JSONP (JSON with padding) data type, just to circumvent Cross-domain restrictions

If you want to pass event or function calls, you will need a third-party plugin, here is a sample:
http://calibrate.be/labs/cross-domain-iframe-communication

Comment: Thank you for your answer i fix the problem with convert some jQuery function to JS and i break some JSlint rules like multi-variables declaration.